# Mingw don't link to sdl2 functions

Tags: c++, c, sdl-2

so basicly i want to make a new sdl2 project (lastest version : 2.24.2) so i make a simple program that just print out the version of sdl :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"

#undef main
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    SDL_version nb;
    SDL_GetVersion(&nb);

    printf("sdl version %d.%d.%d", nb.major, nb.major, nb.patch);

    return 0;
}
```

and i'm using this command to compile :

```
gcc src/*.c -o bin/sampleSDL -I include -L lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

and i get error :

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\CDRIC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaOMh5N.o:main.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `SDL_GetVersion'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I use the 32bits version too.

---

also my project have this structure :

```
SampleSDLproject
|-bin
| |-SDL2.dll
| |-sdl2-config
|
|-include
| |-SDL2
| | |-the headers of sdl
|
|-lib
| |-like the sdl lib folder
|
|-src
| |-main.c
```

i tried installing some other c/c++ packages for mingw, installing new version of sdl (started with 2.24.1) but all this didn't worked

oh and i was forced to instal endian.h because of vscode

---

I found the error myself, i just needed to use the `i686-w64-mingw32` folder instead of `x86_64-w64-mingw32`

Comment: *all this didn't worked*. What did it do? Same thing? Eat your cat? Details, my friend, we need details!

Comment: Good minimal example though. Doesn't get much better than that.

Comment: and which working directory are you compiling and linking this from?

Comment: i'm compiling to the parent director of the project (sampleSDLproject)

Comment: the error message indicates that the linker has found the library, but can't find the function - have you got the spelling, case & other stuff right? or maybe it is in another library?

Comment: no it's the right one, it's from a tutorial on youtube to start SDL2 and i just 'copied-paste' all he does (because i thought i was wrong somewhere while doing it before) and it don't work (but it work for him)


also i tryed reinstall mingw and nothing changed

Comment: Probably better to not mention that the info came from a youtube tutorial. They haven't exactly covered themselves in glamour and respect around here.

Comment: vscode said it should work tho (i have the c/c++ extension) and also, check the sdl api and say that it shouldn't work :/

Comment: vscode is not an AI - there is no way it can say that your program "should work"

Comment: it detected no error* :/

Comment: *c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\CDRIC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccaOMh5N.o:main.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `SDL_GetVersion'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status* is an error. Ergo an error was detected. I'll admit the error diagnostic isn't all that helpful in this case.

Comment: oh and it don't work only with sdl, if i try to link lua to a cpp project, it work, so...

Comment: i needed to use the `i686-w64-mingw32` ;( i wan't commit sucide

Comment: Link order can be important. The only needed library is `-lSDL2`.  I have no problem (other than unused `argc` and `argv` warnings) with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=c11 -Ofast -lSDL2 -o sdlver sdlver.c`

Comment: Reminder: clean up comments that are no longer needed, editing anything useful about the question into the question post. @Darkflame, if you found a solution, write up an answer describing what the problem was, how you solved it, and how/why the solution works.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin All three libs are normally needed on Windows (at least that's what `pkg-config` returns). You can get rid of the other two only if you `#undef main`, or something similar.